# ${basedir} is deprecated but not for file-based activation of a profile. Why not always?

Tags: maven

[Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.4/maven-model-builder/#model-interpolation) says that `${basedir}` is deprecated in favor of `${project.basedir}` but with one exception: file-based activation of a profile.  This is also confirmed in the page that describes [profile activation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation).  What's the rationale behind this exception?

Comment: the new property is not supported for profile activation ... there is a bug

Comment: Is there an open Jira issue for this bug?

Comment: I can not see a issue ... https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20MNG%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20%3D%20Profiles

I was surprised that ${basedir} is still in profile activation ...

Comment: I've created one https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short properties like `${basedir}` are deprecated.

So should be consequently remove from all places.

There is a issue for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7895